# Cannot access the files from sharepoint online through Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I was trying to access the files from Sharepoint Online using the Graph API. I have few files in the Sharepoint site in the drive 'Shared Documents', but I could not able to retrieve these files from postman/using Http client.
Passing a valid access token and below are the permission I have.
[image]

Here is the Graph API using to get the file
/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path}

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

It's returning 404 not found error with message 'The resource could not be found.'

Not sure what I am missing. Your help will be greatly apprieciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, looks like the endpoint url you used is not correct. Suppose you have a file called `test.docx` in 'Shared Documents' in SharePoint site. You should get the file like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/test.docx
```

If the file is in a subfolder, you should get the file like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/folder1/test.docx
```

Comment: I have tried it as well but no luck. Here is the URL I am trying
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site_id>/drive/root:/basics.text

Comment: If you just use the url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root, could you get the root folder of Shared Documents'?

Comment: Yes, I could get the root folder please see
"id": "01IEEUS6V6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
 "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-10-03T18:12:51Z",
 "name": "root",
 "webUrl": "https://<site>.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents"

Comment: Then you could try to use  drive/root/children to get all the files under the root folder.

Comment: I got empty value here,
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('<site_id>')/drive/root/children",
    "value": []

Comment: Try to decode the token in https://jwt.ms/ . Check if it has enough permissions

Comment: It has the below permissions got it from decoding
"scp": "Files.Read Files.Read.All Sites.Read.All User.Read profile openid email"
Do we need any additional permissions

Comment: The permissions looks fine. Since you are using delegated permissions, did the user account you used have permissions to the files in the library?

Comment: Yes, both the registered application and the user have the permissions. You can see the screen shot in the question for registered application permissions.